# Opencart module include custom php file issue?

Tags: php, opencart, php-include

I'm trying to create an OpenCart 1.5.1.3 module. The issue I'm having is with including a custom php script.

When I do this in the controller:

```
include('module/simple_html_dom.php');
```

or

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
```

I'm presented with the following error:

> **Notice**: Error: Could not load language module/simple_html_dom! in **D:\xampp\htdocs\store\system\library\language.php** on line **26**

I suspect there's a simple explanation, but just can't work it out.

Comment: look inside the simple_html_dom library and see what it's trying to include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you're still in theory calling from the index.php file, so need to either use a relative path from that, or use a defined variable, which you can find in the config.php file that have all the relevant paths OpenCart uses

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way to include the file I wanted. I'm not sure it's the proper way of doing this but I used the following code - with OpenCart having such little documentation it's not easy to debug and/or develop for it.

```
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'simple_html_dom.php');
```

DIR_SYSTEM is OpenCart's /system folder, so I placed my simple_html_dom.php file in there and voila, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in opencart. i have to install file i have something like

```
<?php include 'i_header.tpl';?>
```

I replace it with

```
<?php include (DIR_TEMPLATE. '/module/---your module name ---/i_header.tpl');?>
```

and it works. You can chose the correct path name which under the config file.

```
ROOT/config.php

ROOT/admin/config.php
```

I hope this helps.